# Visual studio 2015: Add -> "New Web Role Project" is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I using Visual studio 2015 with C#. A month ago, I created a Cloud Service project. Now, I want to create a New Web Role Project in the existing Cloud Service. But, the options are locked for me.

This is how it's looks like:
[image]

- I not in "Running" mode.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please check if you've got any errors in the .cscfg files. That would be one condition where we block you form adding new roles.